# save info to database after getting device current location (navigator.location.getCurrentPosition), React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, currentlocation

I want to save some info to the database , but should happen after user location function is done getting the current user location.

```
async function getImmediate() {
        let coord;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          async position => {
            const latitude = await JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
            const longitude = await JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
            coord = await position.coords.latitude;
          },
          error => Alert.alert(error.message),
          {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 1000
          }
        );
    
        return coord;
      }

async function saveNow(){
let coordinates = await getImmediate();

//save to the database
console.log(coordinates)
}
```

i get null values and undefined instead.

i will be grateful for your help as it seems am not locating where the problem is quick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promises to achieve what you're trying to do. The below code should work and return the result:

```
function getImmediate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const latitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
            const longitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
            resolve({ latitude, longitude});
          },
          error => Alert.alert(error.message),
          {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 1000
          }
        )
    );
}

async function saveNow(){
  let coordinates = await getImmediate();

  //save to the database
  console.log(coordinates)
}
```